# Cannot install Microsoft Project 2010

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, 64-bit, microsoft-project-2010

I have a Windows 7 x64 OS. I have installed Microsoft Office 2010 32 bit in it. When I tried installing Project 2010 it failed. I have run it as administrator but still no progress.

I get these 2 errors

```
Error: OptionDependency: Indirect dependencies are not supported. Option WISPHidden has a lead WISPFiles which also has 1 leads.

MSI(INFO): 'DEBUG: Error 2203:  Database: C:\MSOCache\All Users\{91140000-0057-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C\ShellUI.MST. Cannot open database file. System error -2147287038'
```

I could not get a proper response elsewhere. I do not want to uninstall the rest of the Office 2010 products and start from scratch. Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: I am trying to add only a 32 bit version of Project on a X64 bit system

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you have any 32 bit component of office then you will not be able to install a 64 bit single component on that same system.

Hope this help

Comment: The comment below his question says he is trying to add a 32bit component to a 32bit Office package on a 64bit system. So this would not be an issue.